# ZeroMQ thread/task advice

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, zeromq, netmq

I have a a task that is running this method for my Sub/Pub pattern. The problem i see is that this loop will hang until data is received. If i want to change the Topic or the IP, i can't get this task to end. If i use a thread i can kill it - but that seems like an ugly solution. Is there a good asynchronous way to set up the receiving end of my subscriber.

```
ReceiveTask = new Task(ReceiveData);
ReceiveTask.Start();

private void ReceiveData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] messageTopicReceived = SubSocket.ReceiveFrameBytes();
        byte[] messageReceived = SubSocket.ReceiveFrameBytes();
    }
    //Code that uses byte array and do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the Try extension instead, it has the following signature:

```
public static bool TryReceiveFrameBytes([NotNull] this IReceivingSocket socket, TimeSpan timeout, out byte[] bytes)
```

That would allow you to pass a `TimeSpan.Zero` as the `timeout` which will make it a non-blocking call. With the `while(true)` that would work fine but you would probably need to add a `Task.Delay` or `Thread.Sleep` in there. A `Task.Delay` would work best as it accepts a `CancellationToken`. That token can be cancelled from a different thread to quickly get out of the loop. Something along these lines:

```
private void ReceiveData(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        bool receivedTopicMessage = SubSocket.TryReceiveFrameBytes(TimeSpan.Zero, out byte[] messageTopicReceived);
        bool receivedMessage = SubSocket.TryReceiveFrameBytes(TimeSpan.Zero, out byte[] messageReceived);

        Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    //Code that uses byte array and do stuff
}
```

Comment: I did this bool `worked1 = SubSocket.TryReceiveFrameBytes(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), out topic);
                    bool worked2 = SubSocket.TryReceiveFrameBytes(out bytes);
                    if (!worked1 || !worked2) continue; ` Worked great!